# Passing std::string by reference in getters and setters

Tags: c++

Ok, so my C++ book is trying to teach me that this is the correct way to write getters and setters for string variables:

```
std::string mFirstName;

void Employee::setEmployeeFirstName(std::string& firstName)
    {this->mFirstName = firstName;}
 std::string& Employee::getEmployeeFirstName() const;
```

But when I'm trying to write the implementation for the getter:

```
{return this->mFirstName;}
```

it doesn't work.
edit-> error that comes up:

```
qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type "std::__cxx11::string &" to initializer of type "const std::__cxx11::string"C/C++(433)
```

I've been always passing Strings by value so I don't know what I'm doing wrong and also, is it really a more efficient way?

Comment: Are you sure your book wasn't suggesting `std::string const&`?

Comment: what type of `mFirstName`? Update the question with a minimal reproducible example, please

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. If you have an error then add that to the question.

Comment: If that would be allowed there would be an easy way to modify a member of a `const` object. Think about what the `const` means on the method declaration

Comment: I edited my question. Also, I double-checked and definitely, there's no const&

Comment: Either the return type is `std::string const&` meaning you are returning a reference to the object but you can not use the reference to modify the object, or you return `std::string` which returns a copy of the object (thus you can not change the object with the returned value). The reason these are your choices is that get `get()` method is `const` so you should not be able to modify the object with the method (or any value returned from the method).

Comment: You may want to use a different reference book.  The syntax `this->` is only necessary to differentiate between members and parameters *that have the same name*.  To avoid this conflict (and the need for `this->`) choose a naming convention for your members that is different than the parameters, such as using an "m_" prefix.